# How to convert 2019-03-26T04:31:40-05:00 like string into timestamp in Java?

Tags: java, date, date-format, java-time

I want to change my time got from server and save into the database using the following format - "25-MAR-19 01.23.42.121000000 AM"

How can I do that using Java?

Tried following code which didn't help

```
import java.sql.Date;
import java.time;
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        final String selectedStart = "2019-03-26T04:31:40-05:00";
        final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss-XXX'");
        final LocalDate parsedDate = LocalDate.parse(selectedStart, formatter);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `java.sql.Date` doing there?

Comment: You shouldn't store date/time values as string in the database, use the proper type (TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE) and use `java.time.OffsetDateTime` to store it using a JDBC 4.2 (or higher) compliant driver.

Comment: You say you want to store date with a precision of nano seconds but what is the point if what your receive is in seconds? Any precision beyond whole seconds will just be made up?

Comment: Related: [Converting ISO 8601-compliant String to java.util.Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201925/converting-iso-8601-compliant-string-to-java-util-date) (just ignore the many answers using the troublesome and outdated `SimpleDateFormat` class).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't totally understand your question but if you want just the date part you can use Ole.V.V answer orjust use :

```
LocalDate d = LocalDate.parse(selectedStart.split("T")[0]);
```

Edit

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(selectedStart);
String str = odt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-uuuu hh.mm.ss.SSSSS a"));
```

Comment: This also gives only date.My input is this - 2019-03-26T04:31:40-05:00 and output I expect is this 26-MAR-19 04.31.40.121000000 AM

Comment: @mashkurm I edit my answer you can try that solution, I dont test it sorry (using phone to answer )

Comment: It works and yields `26-Mar-2019 04.31.40.00000 AM`. For more decimals on the seconds just add more capital `S` in the format pattern.

Comment: Thank you @Ole V.V. for testing it for me,  I wonder if that is a good idea to add 9 time `S` in the format, you don't think it's a little ugly and maybe the OP doesn't want all that details?

Comment: We can just let the OP decide. He knows best what is desired.

Answer (score 3):

Don’t define your own formatter. Use the built-in `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME`.

```
    final String selectedStart = "2019-03-26T04:31:40-05:00";
    final LocalDate parsedDate = LocalDate.parse(selectedStart, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME);
    System.out.println(parsedDate);
```

> 2019-03-26

**What went wrong in your code?**

Two of the characters in your format pattern string are wrong:

1. The offset is `-05:00`, the minus is part of it (it could have been a `+` instead for a positive UTC offset). So delete it from your format pattern.
2. Single quotes (apostrophes) may be set around literal parts as you are doing correctly in `'T'`. You cannot have an unmatched single quote as in the end of your format pattern string. Just delete that too.

**Further tips**

- `LocalDate` is the wrong class to use when you want to store date *and time of day* into your database. A `LocalDate` holds a date without time of day. You probably want `OffsetDateTime`.
- Don’t care about format when storing into you database. Just hand the datetime object (for example your `OffsetDateTime`) to your JDBC driver or JPA implementation and let it take care of the rest.

Comment: -5.00 is a timestamp, stating the timezone. I need a format like this 25-MAR-19 01.23.42.121000000 AM, and not only date.